# How to get the time remaining for an api response to get resolved in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

As you can see below is a network tab that shows the time taken & the loading indicator (on right - green).

Idea is to create a loading indicator that matches something similar (like a real progress bar, & not just some loading animation)

How can we achieve something in angular using rxjs?

[image]

Or atleast get this progress bar values from the network tab in to the angular app. Which then later can be cast in to something meaningful (progress bar/graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses two HTTP events to handle this:
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType

UploadProgress and DownloadProgress. You also need to include `reportProgress: true` as a parameter on the optional section of your http method.

(Note: for multiple upload/downloads at the same time you would want to use an array of subjects and forkjoin them together at the end. Alexander can explain it better here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/rxjs-recipes-forkjoin-with-the-progress-of-completion-for-bulk-network-requests-in-angular-5d585a77cce1

```
public upload(file: File): Observable<any> {
const result = new Subject<any>();   //the subject that will track progress
const fileUploadResult = {
  percentComplete: 0,  // the property you will have emitted to show progress.
  error: false  // you can also add on error, result, or any other variable needed
};
result.next(fileUploadResult);

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, file.name);

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.endpointURL, formData, {
  reportProgress: true, // IMPORTANT: flag to tell it to report the progress
  responseType: 'text'
});

 this.httpClient.request(req).subscribe(
  event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {  // if progress, get the % and emit it.
      const percentComplete = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total) - 1;
      result.next({
        percentComplete,
        error: false
      });
    } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      result.next({
        percentComplete: 100,
        error: false,
        result: event.body
      });
      result.complete();
    }
  }, error => this.handleError(error, result));

return result;
}
```

So anyways, what you do is return the subject, or you can be safe an return an observable `return result as Observable<any>;`

handleError in my case is something like this, but it needs to get the subject to be able to emit to it:

```
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse, result: Subject<FileUploadResult>) {
    const x: any = error;
    try {
      const errorResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(x).message);
      result.next({
        percentComplete: 100,
        error: true,
        errorMessage: errorResponse.message,
        errors: errorResponse.errors
      });
    } catch {
      result.next({
        percentComplete: 100,
        error: true
      });
    }
    result.complete();
```

The actual subscription to such a method looks like this (I have my example doing a bit more special case handling, but hopefully the idea comes across):

```
 this.uploadService.upload(this.file).subscribe(
      r => {
        this.progress = r;
        this.showDelete = false;
        if (r.percentComplete === 100) {
          this.uploadComplete = true;
          if (r.error) {
            this.bar.nativeElement.classList.add('file-upload__upload-failure');
            this.progress = null;
            title = 'Upload Failed';
            if (this.basicError) {
              message = 'The upload failed.  Please try again later.';
            } else {
              if (r.errors) {
                errorList = r.errors;
              }
              if (r.errorMessage) {
                message = r.errorMessage;
              } else {
                message = 'The upload failed.  Please try again later.';
              }
            }
          } else {
            this.successBanner = true;
```

Hope this helps some people, Happy Coding!++